How to disable Pop Up Your responses to this survey are anonymous. on blogger adsense?
enter image description here
I'm very new to AdSense, and out of curiosity I tried all the features in AdSense, but after I accidentally activated the pop up survey, it seemed very annoying. How do I do it please help me to turn off the servey pop up in AdSense
enter image description here
